# US juror qualification: could a stripper be a juror on a Sunday school teacher?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, jury

I have just watched the "Eleven Angry Jurors", a sequel with the CSI, Crime Scene Investigation. One of the jurors was a stripper. The case was described as a high-profile, murder.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0534680/

US courts explain a juror has to be a United States citizen, at least 18 years of age, reside primarily in the judicial district for one year, be adequately proficient in English to satisfactorily complete the juror qualification form, and have no disqualifying mental or physical condition; he or she also cannot be currently subject to felony charges punishable by imprisonment for more than one year, and he or she must never have been convicted of a felony (unless civil rights have been legally restored).

http://www.uscourts.gov/services-forms/jury-service/juror-qualifications

There would not be mention on potential for social bias. I imagine, a stripper would be biased against a religious spinster, as a Sunday school teacher, and well, a stripper would not be my idea for the law.

Comment: Jurors' biases have different impact on different cases. These can't be managed through juror qualifications; instead they are managed through the juror selection process for each case. A stripper would be more likely to be excused from the jury if the murder had happened in a strip club. A religious spinster might be excused if the case had an important religious angle. These are specific decisions. There's no general answer other than "yes, it is possible."

Comment: Following you: a stripper would not be excused if a religious spinster got accused of murder. This means the stripper would be prone to say "guilty". Religious spinsters do not sell own bodies for cash, and the stripper might feel this is a kind of superiority: "she never did what I had to do for living". There should be a legal resolve.

Comment: You misunderstand my point, I think. One cannot say whethera stripper will think one way or another based solely on her occupation. Lawyers will try to get a favorable jury, looking at individuals, not necessarily their occupations. Maybe there's a stripper who would be particularly sympathetic to religious spinsters. Some strippers even *are* religious, for that matter.

Comment: As many modern news stories will allude to....  "religious" and "stripper" may not have dramatically different views on sexuality.  A profession is a profession... it doesn't necessarily make the individual.

Comment: Scott: I am pretty much made of linguistics (some 80%). :) Phoog: I view commercial sex as a bodily compromise, more than likely to result in different attitudes. Me included, there would be people who would not “do it” even in extreme circumstances, and the reason would be in mentality as well as emotionality.

Comment: What's the question? If its "could a stripper be a juror", yes, they could.  Everything else is unclear opinionated speculation.

Comment: "Opinionated" looks judgmental, therefore we would share a "flaw". Just funny to think you'd go to or live in a country where people partaking with commercial sex would be entitled to judge on you. I do not mean to propose another flaw, but obviously, the Founding Fathers meant that or ... commercial sex "professionals" were excluded from the call. ;)  Commercial sex was illegal then and not taken into account.

Comment: Some survey in the UK found out that a huge number of people working in the sex industry have other jobs. And many of them are religious. It's not unlikely that you can find a stripper who is religious, works as a sunday school teacher, and is a spinster (a woman not in any relationship with a man). Go read the bible, her name was Magdalena.

Comment: @gnasher729 Funny world; I've been making my website to include also Wycliffe, and this is exactly what I would not have (and I believe I could not have) for a companion to grammar work: the story of Mary Magdalene. Yet it would be moral enough, for a court of law. https://onethinktionary.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 5):

One option would be for an attorney to spend one of their peremptory challenges, which they could do as long as the juror is not a member of a racial minority ([Batson v. Kentucky, 476 U.S. 79](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/476/79/case.html)). Even then you can, you just have to give a valid reason other than race. Otherwise, the side wishing to strike for cause has to show that there is reasonable doubt that the prospective juror can be impartial (basing their decision just on the evidence presented and the law as explained by the court). Turning the accused / juror relation around, one might be able to strike for cause if the stripper was accused of some form of grave immorality and if the spinster was a leader of a radically puritanical religious sect that held that strippers must fry for said grave immorality crimes. The underlying assumption is that any prospective juror will be impartial, unless they say (or said, or have done) something that shows otherwise.